# print tqdm internal counter value

Tags: python, tqdm

How to print tqdm internal counter value? Need this to avoid using extra enumerate wrapper. Somehow `.n` attribute is not working

```
# my example:
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
s = 'abcd'
pb = tqdm(s)
for character in pb:
    print(pb.n, end = ' ')

output   >>> 0 0 0 0
expected >>> 0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons, tqdm doesn't update the `n` parameter immediately, but only after both a certain number of iterations and a certain time have elapsed (relevant source code [here](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/0bb91857eca0d4aea08f66cf1c8949abe0cd6b7a/tqdm/std.py#L1177)). The empty loop is too quick to allow the time condition to be true on a modern computer.

You can adjust these waiting intervals by setting `miniters` and `mininterval` to force `pb.n` to be updated every loop:

```py
rec = []
s = "abcd"
pb = tqdm(s, miniters=1, mininterval=0)
for character in pb:
    print(pb.n, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

When tqdm prints, in order to keep the loadbar in the same line, it has a parameter of carriage return (\r). The pb.n is printed but immediately erased by the progress bar. You can see it with the debugger adding a breakpoint.

[image]

Without the debugger, I had the same result as you. I had to add

```py
pb.update()
```

in the loop in order to have the correct behavior.